# Finding number of NaT

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to find a number of `Not A Time` values in a grouping:

```
ID    Date         eVal
ddd   2014-02-12   2
ddd   2014-02-13   2
ddd   NaT          2
aaa   2014-02-12   3
aaa   2014-02-13   3
aaa   2014-02-14   3
```

I basically need to add a new column which indicates the `(number of NaT incidences for that ID)`

How do I find that number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
df['NaT'] = df['Date'].isnull() * 1
df.groupby('ID')['NaT'].sum()
```